# Do nothing when the first checkbox is selected and then it will add .10 to the original value for every next checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes and I want the Original price to stay the same when the 1st checkbox is selected and then add 0.10 to the original price for every following checkbox chosen. This should also reset the original value back to its initial state when none are selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let originalPrice = +$('.totalPrice').html();

    var firstChecked = true;

    $("#calculate input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        var priceTotal = originalPrice;
        var checkboxesSelected = $("#calculate input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

        if(firstChecked && checkboxesSelected){
            firstChecked = false;
        }else if(!firstChecked){
            priceTotal += (checkboxesSelected - 1) * 0.1;
        }
        $('.totalPrice').html(priceTotal.toFixed(1));
    });
    $("#calculate input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        if(!$("#calculate input[type='checkbox']:checked").length){
            firstChecked = true;
            originalPrice = 2;
            $('.totalPrice').html(originalPrice);
         }


    });
});
```